# ReNew Java sign certificate

Tags: java, security, certificate, x509certificate, keytool

I mast reenroll with the correct locality spelling full "Ancona" in the state field.
Now state field is "AN"

How can i change only ST in my keystore?
have you a example?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change any information in a certificate without regenerating a new public/private key pair (and getting a CA to issue a new certificate). If you could it would kind of defeat the whole point!